# Duplicate Encoder codewars java Junit exception

Tags: java, junit

I am doing a kata on Codewars named "Duplicate Encoder". 
The code I have written does its job correctly, but junit(4.12) insists it does not for some reason. Both on the website and in my IDE (Eclipse). I have no idea why that is. Could someone shine some light on this issue? Thanks.

The class to be tested:

```
package com.danman;

import java.util.*;

public class Person {

static String encode(String word){

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    List<String> bank = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder wordTwo = new StringBuilder("");

    //1: create a list of all unique elements in the string

    for (int n = 0; n < word.length(); n++) {
        String temp = word.substring(n, n+1);
        if (temp.equals(" ")){continue;}
        bank.add(temp);
    }

    for (int r = 0; r <word.length(); r++){
        List<String> bankTwo = bank;
        Iterator<String> it = bankTwo.iterator();
        String tempTwo = word.substring(r, r+1);
        int count = 0;

        //2: iterate through the list of elements and append the appropriate       token to the StringBuilder
        while (it.hasNext()){
            if (it.next().equals(tempTwo)){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count <= 1){
            wordTwo.append("(");
        } else {
            wordTwo.append(")");
        }`enter code here`
    }
    word = wordTwo.toString();
    return word;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person rinus = new Person();
    System.out.println(rinus.encode("Prespecialized"));
}
```

Junit file:

```
package com.danman;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


public class PersonTest {
@Test
public void test() {
  assertEquals(")()())()(()()(", Person.encode("Prespecialized"));
  assertEquals("))))())))", Person.encode("   ()(   "));
}
```

Comment: what is your code suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code, first assert is ok. I don't know why encoding `"   ()(   "` should return `"))))())))"`. You iterate through bank list of characters in given string (spaces are excluded in that list), checking whether there is more than one occurence of each character from the word in the bank list. When you check if there is more than one space, the answer will be no, appending `(`, because count value will equal `0` (due to spaces being excluded from the bank list).

The second assert should rather be

```
assertEquals("((()()(((", Person.encode("   ()(   "));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I amended the 2nd assertion. The task description said to ignore spaces, so the test was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DuplicateEncoder {
    static String encode(String word) {
        word=word.toUpperCase();
        ArrayList<String> stack1 =new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
            String t = word.substring(i,i+1);
            stack1.add(t);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
        Iterator<String> iterator =stack1.iterator();
            String t = word.substring(i,i+1);
        int count=0;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            if(iterator.next().equals(t)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>1){
            stringBuilder.append(")");
        }
        else stringBuilder.append("(");

    }
    word=stringBuilder.toString();
        return word;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        encode("Pup");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).